# connect a password of mssql server to other services in using docker

Tags: php, sql-server, docker, docker-compose

Hello there I am practicing Docker and Docker-compose. It is quite fun and cool.

I am a beginner also. I am trying to make a docker-compose.yml file for creating 3 services ( I dont know if this is the right term for it) the services are follows:

1. frontend
2. backend
3. database

Here is my code

**docker-compose.yml**

```
frontend:
    image: eboraas/apache-php
    build: ./dockerfile-frontend
    links:
     - database
    environment:
     - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=embuscado29
    ports:
     - "<server public IP>:8082:8082"
    volumes:
     - ./code:/code
     - ./html:/var/www/html
backend:
    image: eboraas/apache-php
    build: ./dockerfile-frontend
    links:
     - database
    environment:
     - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=embuscado29
    ports:
     - "<server public IP>:8082:8082"
    volumes:
     - ./code:/code
     - ./html:/var/www/html
database:
    image: mariadb
    environment:

    volumes:
     - ./database:/var/lib/mysql
```

My question how can I connect the frontend and backend services to the database service? my database will be a mssql server

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to separate frontend and backend, especially if both have the same image. You also should specify `image` **or** `build`, not both. For database, all your environmental variables go to `environment`. Using mssql is not a very bright idea, but if you wish...

This is how I would have done it:

```
version: "2"

web:
    image: php:5-apache
    links:
     - database
    environment:
     - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=embuscado29
    ports:
     - "<server public IP>:8082:8082"
    volumes:
     - ./code:/code
     - ./html:/var/www/html
mssql:
    image: rsmoorthy:mssql
    environment:
        - MSSQL_DB_HOST: mssql
        - MSSQL_DB_PORT: 1433
        - MSSQL_DB_USER: sa
        - MSSQL_DB_PASSWORD: hello
        - MSSQL_DB_DATABASE: test
```

Comment: Okay I will try that

Comment: In the volume table, in the web service, the html is a folder?

Comment: I don't know, it depends on your project. If you mindlessly copied `docker-compose.yml` from somewhere, then it's hard to say.